# How to extract a word from a column to their own separate column in r

Tags: r, stringr

For example I have a column where the characters go something like this

```
"Object=house colour=blue size=big", "Object=roof colour=red size=small", "Object=window colour=green size=medium"
```

I want to extract just the word after colour and create a new column. so it would look like this

```
"blue", "red", "green"
```

I have started trying to do this with `str_extract`  but am very lost on how to specify things. So far I have

```
colour<- str_extract(string = df, pattern = "(?<=colour= ).*(?=\\,)")
```

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no space after the `=` and also, we can use `\\S+` to specify one or more non-white space

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = df, pattern = "(?<=colour=)\\S+")
[1] "blue"  "red"   "green"
```

#### data

```
df <- c("Object=house colour=blue size=big", "Object=roof colour=red size=small", 
"Object=window colour=green size=medium")
```

Comment: @MariaFaleeva `+` signifies one or more characters `\\S` - non-white space character.  So, when combined it says one or more non-whitespace character

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

c("Object=house colour=blue size=big", "Object=roof colour=red size=small", "Object=window colour=green size=medium") %>% 
  str_extract("(?<=colour\\=)\\S+")

#> [1] "blue"  "red"   "green"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert to dcf, and turn this to a data.frame:

```
read.dcf(textConnection(paste(chartr("= ", ":\n", text), collapse = "\n\n")), all =TRUE)
  Object colour   size
1  house   blue    big
2   roof    red  small
3 window  green medium
```

Then you can select the column you want

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
df <- c(
  "Object=house colour=blue size=big", 
  "Object=roof colour=red size=small", 
  "Object=window colour=green size=medium"
)

res <- data.frame(
  object_info = df,
  object_colour = gsub(
    ".*\\s+colour\\=(\\S+).*",
    "\\1",
    df
  ),
  row.names = NULL,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

res
```